Vue memory leaks in table using dynamic components
In our Vue/Vuetify 3 project we have generic table component which conditionally renders different components as table cells.
Unfortunately, tables are causing big memory leaks.
It is a big component, so I removed all the lines of code that I thougth are not important
<template>
  <v-data-table-server :items="items">
    <!--  Rows  -->
    <template #tbody="{ items: rows }">
      <tbody v-if="!rows.length">
        <tr
          class="v-data-table-rows-loading">
          <td :colspan="headers.length + showSelect">{{ $t(`common.${loading ? 'loading' : 'emptyList'}`) }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <draggable
        v-else
        :list="rows"
        draggable=".draggable-row"
        ghost-class="ghost"
        tag="tbody"
        @end="onRowDrop" >
        
        <tr v-for="item in rows"
            :key="item[identifierColumn]"
            :class="[draggableRows && !item.unremovable && 'draggable-row', item.color_raw]"
            tabindex="0"
            @click.exact.stop="!editingWidth.columnName && $emit('click:row', item)"
            @click.ctrl.stop="!editingWidth.columnName && $emit('click:row', item, true)"
            @keydown.enter="!editingWidth.columnName && $emit('click:row', item)">
          <td v-for="(column, index) in headers"
              :key="column.key + resetColumnWidthsKey"
              style="height: 40px;"
              :style="editingWidth.columnName === column.key ? `max-width: ${editingWidth.width}px; width: ${editingWidth.width}px;` : getTdStyle(column, index)"
              :class="[item[column.key] && item[column.key].cell_color]"
              :column="index">
            <slot :name="`item.${column.key}`"
                  :item="item">
              <div v-if="column.key === 'select'"
                   :style="{width: '28px'}">
                <v-checkbox v-model="selectedItemsIds"
                            class="configurable-table-select"
                            :value="item[identifierColumn]"
                            hide-details
                            density="compact"
                            color="primary"
                            @click.stop
                />
              </div>
              <div v-else>
                  
                <DraggableIcon v-if="column.type === 'draggable'"
                               :disabled="item.unremovable" />
                <component :is="getComponentName(column.type)"
                           v-else
                           :class="[item.is_read === 0 && 'font-weight-bold']"
                           :default-value="$t('common.noData')"
                           :row="item"
                           :column-name="column.key"
                           :disabled="item.unremovable"
                           :remote-dictionary="getRemoteDictionary(column.key)"
                           v-bind="{...column.props, ...$attrs, class: ''}"
                           :tab-index="index + 1"
                           :identifier-column="identifierColumn"
                           :format="column.format"
                           :patch-action="patchAction"
                           :action-prefix="actionPrefix"
                           :submodule-form-id="submoduleFormId"
                           :allow-overflow="allowOverflow"
                           :is-create-mode="isCreateMode"
                           :module-name="moduleName"
                           :submodule-name="submoduleName"
                           :can-editable="item.can_editable"
                           :parent-component-name="parentComponentName"
                           :dictionary="column.dictionary"
                           @click="$emit('click:cell-component', { row: item, column: column })"
                           @cellLoading="onCellLoading"
                           @editingWidth="editingWidth = $event" />
              </div>
            </slot>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </draggable>
    </template>
  </v-data-table-server>
</template>

<script>
import { getColumnComponentName } from '@/services/table.service'
import { VueDraggableNext  } from 'vue-draggable-next'
import { getDictionaries } from '@/services/dictionary.service.js'

export default {
  name: 'ConfigurableTable',
  components: {
    draggable: VueDraggableNext
  },  
  props: {
    modelValue: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => []
    },
    columns: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => []
    },
    items: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => []
    },
    totalElements: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0
    },
    hideIdentifierColumn: {
      type: Boolean
    },
    identifierColumn: {
      type: String,
      default: 'id'
    },
    loading: {
      type: Boolean
    },
    remotePagination: {
      type: Boolean
    },
    height: {
      type: [String, Number],
      default: '350px'
    },
    cursorPointer: {
      type: [Boolean, Number],
      default: false
    },
    draggableRows: {
      type: Boolean
    },
    showSelect: {
      type: Boolean
    },
    disablePagination: {
      type: Boolean
    },
    moduleName: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      default: ''
    },
    submoduleName: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      default: ''
    },
    submoduleFormId: {
      type: [String, Number],
      default: null
    },
    relativeEntitySubmoduleId: {
      type: [String, Number],
      default: null
    },
    useSavedListSettings: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    isCreateMode: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    patchAction: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => ({})
    },
    parentComponentName: {
      type: String,
      default: null
    },
    customPageTransPrefix: {
      type: String,
      default: null
    },
    actionPrefix: {
      type: String,
      default: null
    },
    isPinDialog: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    footer: {
      type: Object,
      default: null
    },
    page: {
      type: Number,
      default: null
    },
    allColumns: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => []
    },
    allowOverflow: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    relativeModuleName: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      default: ''
    },
    isFirstLoad: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    tabName: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    },
    listColumnSizes: {
      type: Array,
      default: null
    },
    submoduleId: {
      type: Number,
      default: null
    },
    staticListSettings: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    resetColumnWidths: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    draggableDisabled: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    level: {
      type: Number,
      default: null
    },
    customBody: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      orderedColumns: [],
      backendPerPage: 10,
      sorting: {
        column: null,
        isDesc: false
      },
      remoteDictionaries: [],
      cellLoading: false,
      curCol: undefined,
      pageX: undefined,
      curColWidth: undefined,
      curIndex: undefined,
      curMinWidth: undefined,
      columnsWidths: [],
      listSettings: {
        per_page: 50,
        page: 1,
        column: undefined,
        direction: undefined
      },
      scrollingLeft: false,
      scrollingRight: false,
      resetColumnWidthsKey: 0,
      editingWidth: {},
    }
  },
  computed: {
    headers() {
      // For draggable columns draggable: col.draggable === undefined ? true : col.draggable,          return [

        ...this.orderedColumns.map((col) => ({
          ...col,
          draggable: false,
          value: col.key,
          sortable: this.isCreateMode ? false : col.sortable
        }))
      ]
    },
    selectedItemsIds: {
      get() {
        return this.modelValue
      },
      set(items) {
        this.$emit('update:modelValue', items)
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onRowDrop({ oldIndex, newIndex }) {

      if (this.draggableDisabled || this.loading || this.cellLoading) return

      this.$emit('changePosition', {
        from: this.items[oldIndex],
        to: this.items[newIndex],
        oldIndex,
        newIndex
      })
    },
    getComponentName(columnType) {
      return getColumnComponentName(columnType, this.parentComponentName)
    },
    getRemoteDictionary(columnKey) {
      return this.remoteDictionaries[columnKey.split('.')[0]]
    },
    onCellLoading(loading) {
      this.cellLoading = loading
    },
  }
}
</script>

Method 'getComponentName' takes name from js file where we have declared a bunch of components
export const getColumnComponentName = (columnType) => {
  switch (columnType) {
    case 'string':
      return 'DefaultTableCell'
    case 'checkbox':
      return 'BooleanIndicator'
    case 'editable':
      return 'EditableCell'
    case 'relationship_object':
      return 'ListCell'
    case 'hyperlink':
      return 'HyperlinkCell'
    case 'download':
      return 'DownloadCell'
    case 'initialsRelationshipObject':
      return 'InitialsRelationshipCell'
    case 'label':
      return 'LabelCell'
    case 'rangeInput':
      return 'RangeInputCell'
    case 'avatar':
      return 'AvatarCell'
    case 'copyInput':
      return 'CopyInputCell'
    case 'editableLabel':
      return 'EditableLabelCell'
    case 'actionCheckbox':
      return 'ActionCheckboxCell'
    case 'colorPicker':
      return 'ColorPickerCell'
    case 'attachment':
      return 'AttachmentCell'
    case 'attachments':
      return 'AttachmentsCell'
    case 'modalInput':
      return 'ModalInputCell'
    case 'tagsRelationshipObject':
      return 'TagsRelationshipCell'
    case 'editableString':
      return 'EditableStringCell'
    case 'editableDatePicker':
      return 'EditableDatePickerCell'
    case 'editableDateTimePicker':
      return 'EditableDateTimePickerCell'
    case 'editableTimeInput':
      return 'EditableTimeInputCell'
    case 'editableSelect':
      return 'EditableSelectCell'
    case 'editableRangeInput':
      return 'EditableRangeInputCell'
    case 'editableModal':
      return 'EditableModalCell'
    default:
      return 'DefaultTableCell'
  }
}

and these are registered globally in main.js file
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import { defineAsyncComponent } from 'vue'

const app = createApp(App)

app.component('EditableCell', defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/ModulesComponents/TableComponents/EditableCell.vue')));
app.component('DefaultTableCell', defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/ModulesComponents/TableComponents/DefaultTableCell.vue')));
app.component('BooleanIndicator', defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/ModulesComponents/TableComponents/BooleanIndicatorCell.vue')));
app.component('ListCell', defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/ModulesComponents/TableComponents/ListCell.vue')));
app.component('DraggableIcon', defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/DraggableIcon.vue')));
app.component('HyperlinkCell', defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/ModulesComponents/TableComponents/HyperlinkCell.vue')));
app.component('DownloadCell', defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/ModulesComponents/TableComponents/DownloadCell.vue')));
app.component('InitialsRelationshipCell', defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/ModulesComponents/TableComponents/InitialsRelationshipCell.vue')));
app.component('LabelCell', defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/ModulesComponents/TableComponents/LabelCell.vue')));
app.component('RangeInputCell', defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/ModulesComponents/TableComponents/RangeInputCell.vue')));
app.component('AvatarCell', defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/ModulesComponents/TableComponents/AvatarCell.vue')));
app.component('CopyInputCell', defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/ModulesComponents/TableComponents/CopyInputCell.vue')));
app.component('EditableLabelCell', defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/ModulesComponents/TableComponents/EditableLabelCell.vue')));
app.component('ActionCheckboxCell', defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/ModulesComponents/TableComponents/ActionCheckboxCell.vue')));
app.component('ColorPickerCell', defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/ModulesComponents/TableComponents/ColorPickerCell.vue')));
app.component('AttachmentCell', defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/ModulesComponents/TableComponents/AttachmentCell.vue')));
app.component('AttachmentsCell', defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/ModulesComponents/TableComponents/AttachmentsCell.vue')));
app.component('ModalInputCell', defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/ModulesComponents/TableComponents/ModalInputCell.vue')));
app.component('TagsRelationshipCell', defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/ModulesComponents/TableComponents/TagsRelationshipCell.vue')));
app.component('EditableStringCell', defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/ModulesComponents/TableComponents/EditableStringCell.vue')));
app.component('EditableDatePickerCell', defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/ModulesComponents/TableComponents/EditableDatePickerCell.vue')));
app.component('EditableDateTimePickerCell', defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/ModulesComponents/TableComponents/EditableDateTimePickerCell.vue')));
app.component('EditableTimeInputCell', defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/ModulesComponents/TableComponents/EditableTimeInputCell.vue')));
app.component('EditableSelectCell', defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/ModulesComponents/TableComponents/EditableSelectCell.vue')));
app.component('EditableRangeInputCell', defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/ModulesComponents/TableComponents/EditableRangeInputCell.vue')));
app.component('EditableModalCell', defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/ModulesComponents/TableComponents/EditableModalCell.vue')));

app.mount('#app')

I'm suspecting that's because of usage of dynamic 'component' element, because I replaced it with dummy 'div' and memory leaks disappeared.
We don't want to stop using dynamic cell components, because it will delete a lot of our functionalities. Any idea how to get rid of memory leaks and maintain functionality? Is it even possible? Maybe we should somehow compromise functionality and memory management? Maybe You see other cause of memory leaks?
I don't know if it will be helpful, but we used to have the same problem when using Vue/Vuetify 2 and after migration to 3 it still haunts us.
EDIT
I'm not allowed to give You access to the whole project, but I created a demo app that has the same problem:
https://github.com/pmarchut/vue-memory-leaks-example
If You want to You can clone this repository, run it and inspect the memory leaks in memory tools in browser, when You switch from Projects to Issues and vice versa

This is something that needs to be debugged, you can't solve a problem like this one on paper. You need https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can reproduce the problem. It's possible that it could be narrowed down to vuetify components or draggable

how have you determined there are memory leaks?

Does any of the "cell" components use any 3rd party library component? It is much more likely the leak is caused by cell component rendered and not Vue's "dynamic component" infrastructure

I detected there are memory leaks, because evrytime I change route and render the table the RAM usage on tab in browser is rising and not coming back to normal. In memory tab in chrome devtools I see there are blue pills and memory is not freed. I removed code from template props by props, element by element. I even changed templates of used components into dummy divs with text from backend. Memory leaks maybe sometimes were smaller, but unacceptable everytime and they completely disappeared only when I replaced 'component' with dummy 'div'. That's why I'm suspecting this

I will try to create a working example with this problem and add it to the description
